# CakePHP & AuthComponent unit test doesn't appear to call isAuthorized()

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, authentication, authorization

I am writing unit tests for my UsersController so that users can only edit their own profile. I am using CakePHP 2.4.2 and AuthComponent with Controller authorize to do this.

Auth config:

```
public $components = array(
                      'Auth' => array(
                        'loginRedirect' => '/',
                        'logoutRedirect' => '/',
                        'authenticate' => array('Ldap'),
                        'authError' => 'You are not allowed to access this page',
                        'authorize' => 'Controller'));
```

isAuthorized() in UsersController:

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
  if($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
    return $this->request->params['pass'][0] == $user['id'];
  }
  return false;
}
```

Unit test for edit:

```
public function testEdit() {
  $result = $this->testAction('/users/view/1', array('return' => 'view'));
  $this->assertRegExp('/Adam C Hobaugh/', $result);
  $user = $this->generate('Users', array(
            'components' => array(
              'Session',
              'Auth' => array('user'))));
  $test = array('id' => 1);
  $user->Auth->expects($this->once())->method('loggedIn')
                                      ->with($this->returnValue(true));
  $user->Auth->expects($this->any())->method('user')
                                    ->with($this->returnValue($test));
  $user->Session->expects($this->any())->method('setFlash');
  $result = $this->testAction('/users/edit/1', array(
              'return' => 'headers',
              'data' => array('User' => array( {user array} ))));
  debug($result);
  $this->assertContains('/users', @$result['Location']);
  $result = $this->testAction('/users/view/1', array('return' => 'view'));
  $this->assertRegExp('/John Jacob Doe/', $result);
}
```

I am getting `Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:loggedIn> when invoked 1 time(s). Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.` when I run the test. Also when I changed this->once() to $this->any() and the id in the $test array to 2, a situation that should fail and does from the browser, it succeeds in passing the test.

With those combined, it appears that isAuthorized() is not being called during the unit test. I am at a loss. Thanks for any help that you could give.

Answer (score -2):

First: In your test code you call the view method and not the edit method

Second: isAuthorized() is not for this. With this method you should just define who could acces what functions, there should not be any application business logic.

Third: If you want to limit normal users to edit just their own profile you should change the dit() method to something like this.

```
public function edit() {
  $this->request->data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->User('id');
  if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
      return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
  }
  } else {
    $this->request->data = array('User' => $this->Auth->User());
  }
}
```

And remove echo $this->Form->input('id'); from your edit view.

I am writing a book about this topic. It will be available here soon: https://leanpub.com/CakePHPUserAuthentication/